# Statistical test to find difference in mean for sample that is not normally distributed

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I have a time series that has a non-normal distribution and I'd like to find out if it's mean (or drift of the cumulative sum) is statistially significantly different to zero.

I know that if the time series has a normally distributed return, I could use a pared t-test, but since in my case I would violate that assumptation I'm looking for an alternative.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are you testing a 'before-and-after' scenario? Or is it that you're testing the drift in a random walk?

Comment: trying to find out if a trading strategy is giving a positive return or if it's too early to draw any conclusion. I assume that goes under drift of a non-normal random walk.

Comment: Are you looking at daily data over a short(ish) period of time (say a few weeks)?

Comment: I'm looking at data over a few weeks that contains the pnl of every trade - which I assume is a yes to your question